# Jmeter loop count value behaviour

Tags: jmeter

This is with respect to Jmeter's loop count behavior.

```
Number of threads 4000
ramp up period 800
Thread count 2
Action to be taken after a sample error Continue
Same user on each iteration Yes
Delay thread creation until needed Yes
```

This is resulting in 8000 requests being made in 800 seconds. However, my use case is, 4000 requests in 800 seconds (count=1), then another 4000 in next 800 seconds (count=2).
What changes can I make for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ramp-up period doesn't mean 8000 requests in 800 seconds, it results in:

1. JMeter starts with 1 virtual user and adds 5 virtual users each second for 800 seconds
2. Each virtual user executes [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down for the specified number of iterations
3. When there are no more Samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread is being shut down

My expectation is that you only have 1 Sampler and its response time is relatively low (less than 1 second), you can check the actual amount of virtual users and produced load using [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listeners

If you need to implement 4000 requests for 800 seconds twice the easiest option would be going for the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and configuring it to reach/maintain 5 requests per second throughput for 800 seconds twice with 10 seconds time frame of doing nothing between loops.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the above understanding is correct. However, the response time for each api call varies from 1s to 100s. Also, with the above configuration, what changes should i do in the thread group and how does that affect the req/s?